# How to get friendly URLs to work in a headless implementation?

Tags: 8

I'm planning to implement a headless Drupal 8 with a SPA using React. I've been looking through articles on this subject but have found that most of them are just describing how I can pull data off from Drupal's API services.

In a regular Drupal site, when I create a blog post, the system will create a friendly URL like "www.mydomain.com/articles/my-post-title". When I'm creating the frontend through a view library such as React, that URL is likely not going to work because that will route the user away from my SPA site but to the Drupal page instead.

I understand that the routing part in React is usually handled by a library such as react-router. However, I don't understand how should the friendly links of pages and blog posts created by Drupal be mapped over in react-router.

If I want the friendly links Drupal create to work with my React frontend, how should I approach this in my headless implementation?

Answer (score 1):

if you use drupal headless its mostly up to the front end framework to implement friendly urls

for react you will probably use routes but since this is beyond the scope of this forum the question might also be deemed as irrelevant

Comment: Yes, I understand that the frontend framework usually handles the routing. However, since Drupal creates its own friendly URLs, how do I map those friend URLs which Drupal create over to my frontend router such as react-router? As in, how should I approach the headless implementation?

Comment: then i think you should ask with specific code or specific use case otherwise your question is too broad

Comment: @xenon One way: alter the node view, check the headers for an accept header that your app sends. If it’s application/json, invoke the serialiser on the node and return the node json instead of continuing with the node build. Whatever approach you take will be something manual I suspect, core API is based on REST which doesn’t lend itself to the kind of approach you’re trying to realise. I have to agree with GiorgiosK that it would be most sensible to keep he routing from the two separate applications separate. Trying to jam them together is probably going to cause issues later on